# Show different \newtcbinputlistings in Table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, listings, tcolorbox

From the [solution posted here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/353528/hyperref-not-generating-correct-labels-to-listings), I wanted to get the `\newtcbinputlisting` to show in the table of contents.

I tried using `\lstlistoflistings`, but nothing showed up in the Listing contents page.

I would like the listings to show up in their respective sections but under Listings, like this:

**Listings**

**Data**

1.1 Code Snippet............................3

1.2 Code Snippet............................3

**Results**

1.1 Result from run 1.....................3

Here is the code thus far:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{book}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pdfpages,graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[numbered,framed]{matlab-prettifier}

\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.92}
\definecolor{myblueiii}{RGB}{199,234,253}
\definecolor{mainColor}{RGB}{211, 47, 47} % some dark red
\definecolor{codegreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{codegray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{codepurple}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{backcolour}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.92}
\definecolor{mybluei}{RGB}{0,173,239}
\definecolor{myblueiii}{RGB}{199,234,253}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\newcounter{data}
\newcounter{result}
\newcounter{pythoncode}
\newcounter{matlab}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable,listings}
\newtcbinputlisting[use counter=data]{\inputdata}[3][]{%
    title after break={\centering\footnotesize\itshape\strut Data~\thedata~--~continued},%
     listing only,listing options={xleftmargin=-1mm,#1,style=weka},after upper={\centering\strut Data~\thedata:~#2},%
     listing file={#3},#1}
\newtcbinputlisting[use counter=result]{\inputresult}[3][]{%
enhanced,noparskip,breakable,colback=myblueiii,opacitybacktitle=.8,%
    title after break={\centering\footnotesize\itshape\strut Result~\theresult~--~continued},%
     listing only,listing options={xleftmargin=-1mm,#1,style=mystyleresults},after upper={\centering\strut Result~\theresult:~#2},%
     listing file={#3},#1}

\lstdefinestyle{mystyleresults}{
    commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{black},
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray},
    stringstyle=\color{black},
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
    breakatwhitespace=false,
    breaklines=true,
    captionpos=b,
    keepspaces=true,
    numbers=none,
    numbersep=5pt,
    showspaces=false,
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,
    tabsize=6
}

\lstdefinestyle{weka}{
    numbers=none,
    numbersep=5pt,
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray},
    commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    keywordstyle={[2]\color{magenta}},
    stringstyle=\color{codepurple},
    basicstyle=\footnotesize,
    comment=[l]{\%},
    keywords={@relation,@attribute,@data},
    morekeywords=[2]{real,integer,numeric,string,date},
    breakatwhitespace=false,
    breaklines=true,
    captionpos=b,
    keepspaces=true,
    showspaces=false,
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,
    tabsize=2
}

\begin{filecontents}{result1.txt}
=== Run information ===

Correlation coefficient                  0.5941
Mean absolute error                      2.2173
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{result2.txt}
% 9 attributes
% 188 instances

@relation FIT

@attribute NUMUORS real   % Number of unique operators
@attribute NUMUANDS real  % Number of unique operands
@attribute TOTOTORS real  % Total number of operators

\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\numberwithin{data}{chapter}
\numberwithin{result}{chapter}



\newcommand{\dataref}[1]{%
\hyperref[#1]{\textbf{\color{mybluei}Data \ref{#1}}}%
}

\newcommand{\resultref}[1]{%
\hyperref[#1]{\textbf{\color{mybluei}Result \ref{#1}}}%
}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Data}
\section{Data1}
This is a reference for \dataref{data:D1} shown below.
\inputdata[label={data:D1}]{Code Snippet}{result2.txt}

This is a reference for \dataref{data:D2} shown below.
\inputdata[label={data:D2}]{Code Snippet}{result2.txt}

This is a reference for \dataref{result:R1} shown below.
\inputresult[label={result:R1}]{Result from run 1}{result1.txt}
This is a reference for \resultref{result:R1} shown above.

\chapter{Analysis}
\section{Data44}
This is a reference for \dataref{data:D44} shown below.
\inputdata[label=data:D44]{Code Snippet}{result2.txt}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `list inside=data` or `list inside=result` options and `\tcblistof[\chapter*]{data}{List of Data}` etc. commands to generate and display the `list of...` to generate separate the listings.

The command `\tcblistof[\chapter*]{data}{List of Data}` will use `\chapter*` as the heading command of the list of and the title will be `List of Data` -- any other name or sectioning unit are possible, as well, as an arbitrary command instead of `\chapter*` that uses one argument to `gobble` the name of the list.

Either `title=` or `list entry=` must be given, please change the key values to your needs.

There's **no** easy way to group the Data entries and Results entries under `Listings` however.

Actually, they aren't listings at all, in my point of view.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{book}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pdfpages,graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[numbered,framed]{matlab-prettifier}

\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.92}
\definecolor{myblueiii}{RGB}{199,234,253}
\definecolor{mainColor}{RGB}{211, 47, 47} % some dark red
\definecolor{codegreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{codegray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{codepurple}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{backcolour}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.92}
\definecolor{mybluei}{RGB}{0,173,239}
\definecolor{myblueiii}{RGB}{199,234,253}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\newcounter{data}
\newcounter{result}
\newcounter{pythoncode}
\newcounter{matlab}

\usepackage{hyperref}


\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable,listings}
\newtcbinputlisting[use counter=data,list inside=data,number within=chapter]{\inputdata}[3][]{%
  title={Data~\thedata~ #2},
  title after break={\centering\footnotesize\itshape\strut Data~\thedata~--~continued},%
  listing only,listing options={xleftmargin=-1mm,#1,style=weka},after upper={\centering\strut Data~\thedata:~#2},%
  listing file={#3},#1}
\newtcbinputlisting[use counter=result,list inside=result,number within=chapter]{\inputresult}[3][]{%
  title={#2},
  enhanced,noparskip,breakable,colback=myblueiii,opacitybacktitle=.8,%
  title after break={\centering\footnotesize\itshape\strut Result~\theresult~--~continued},%
  listing only,listing options={xleftmargin=-1mm,#1,style=mystyleresults},after upper={\centering\strut Result~\theresult:~#2},%
  listing file={#3},#1}

\lstdefinestyle{mystyleresults}{
    commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{black},
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray},
    stringstyle=\color{black},
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
    breakatwhitespace=false,
    breaklines=true,
    captionpos=b,
    keepspaces=true,
    numbers=none,
    numbersep=5pt,
    showspaces=false,
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,
    tabsize=6
}

\lstdefinestyle{weka}{
    numbers=none,
    numbersep=5pt,
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray},
    commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    keywordstyle={[2]\color{magenta}},
    stringstyle=\color{codepurple},
    basicstyle=\footnotesize,
    comment=[l]{\%},
    keywords={@relation,@attribute,@data},
    morekeywords=[2]{real,integer,numeric,string,date},
    breakatwhitespace=false,
    breaklines=true,
    captionpos=b,
    keepspaces=true,
    showspaces=false,
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,
    tabsize=2
}

\begin{filecontents}{result1.txt}
=== Run information ===

Correlation coefficient                  0.5941
Mean absolute error                      2.2173
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{result2.txt}
% 9 attributes
% 188 instances

@relation FIT

@attribute NUMUORS real   % Number of unique operators
@attribute NUMUANDS real  % Number of unique operands
@attribute TOTOTORS real  % Total number of operators

\end{filecontents}

%\numberwithin{data}{chapter}
%\numberwithin{result}{chapter}






\newcommand{\dataref}[1]{%
\hyperref[#1]{\textbf{\color{mybluei}Data \ref{#1}}}%
}

\newcommand{\resultref}[1]{%
\hyperref[#1]{\textbf{\color{mybluei}Result \ref{#1}}}%
}

\newcommand{\listofdataname}{List of Data}
\newcommand{\listofresultname}{List of Results}

\begin{document}


\tcblistof[\chapter*]{data}{\listofdataname}
\tcblistof[\chapter*]{result}{\listofresultname}


\chapter{Data}
\section{Data1}
This is a reference for \dataref{data:D1} shown below.
\inputdata[label={data:D1}]{Code Snippet}{result2.txt}

This is a reference for \dataref{data:D2} shown below.
\inputdata[label={data:D2}]{Code Snippet}{result2.txt}

This is a reference for \dataref{result:R1} shown below.
\inputresult[label={result:R1}]{Result from run 1}{result1.txt}
This is a reference for \resultref{result:R1} shown above.

\chapter{Analysis}
\section{Data44}
This is a reference for \dataref{data:D44} shown below.
\inputdata[label=data:D44]{Code Snippet}{result2.txt}
\end{document}
```

[image]