# Adjust vertical spacing of image within listing environment

Tags: graphics, listings, tcbinputlisting

In the code below, I wanted to be able to center the image to the heading text like that shown below, where the center of the image is in line with the center of the text:

[image]

Here is the code that I have thus far [includes inputs from [Dr. Hupfer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/353692/show-different-newtcbinputlistings-in-table-of-contents) and Sheppard]:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt, oneside, fleqn, openright]{report}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{french}
\setotherlanguages{english}

\newcommand{\codeimg}{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{example-image-a}}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pdfpages,graphicx}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.92}

\definecolor{mainColor}{RGB}{211, 47, 47} % some dark red

\renewcommand\lstlistingname{Code}
\lstset{
    language=Python,
    numbers=left,
    numbersep= 7mm,
    numberstyle=\color{Black},
    stepnumber=1,
    tabsize=3,
    breakatwhitespace=false,
    breaklines=true,
    captionpos=b,
    basicstyle=\color{Black}\ttfamily,
    commentstyle=\color{LimeGreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{BurntOrange}\bfseries,
    stringstyle=\color{WildStrawberry},
    keywords={var, func, extends},
    frame=leftline,
    framesep=0mm,
    xleftmargin=3mm,% marge ajouté à gauche du tableau (à configurer en dernier pour l'alignement global du tableau)
    framesep=2mm, %distance texte bord du cadre (limite de la background color)
    framerule=0mm,
    abovecaptionskip=5mm,
    aboveskip=\baselineskip,
    belowskip=\baselineskip
}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\newcounter{data}
\newcounter{result}
\newcounter{pythoncode}
\newcounter{matlab}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable,listings}
\newtcblisting[use counter=lstlisting]{codeblock}[2][]{%
        enhanced,noparskip,breakable,colback=light-gray,colframe=DarkSlateGray,opacitybacktitle=.8,%
        fonttitle=\bfseries,before upper={\hspace*{-1em}\includegraphics[height=\baselineskip]{example-image-a}~#2},%
        title after break={\centering\footnotesize\itshape\strut\lstlistingname~\thelstlisting~--~continued},%
        listing only,listing options={xleftmargin=-1mm},
        after upper={\centering\strut\lstlistingname~\thelstlisting:~#2},
        frame hidden,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,boxrule=0pt,frame code={\draw[gray,line width=2mm] ([xshift=-0.5pt]frame.north west) -- ([xshift=-0.5pt]frame.south west);},#1}

\newtcbinputlisting[use counter=matlab,list inside=matlab,number within=chapter]{\inputmatlab}[3][]{listing options={style=Matlab-editor},%
        enhanced,noparskip,breakable,colback=light-gray,colframe=DarkSlateGray,opacitybacktitle=.8,%
        fonttitle=\bfseries,before upper={\hspace*{-1em} \includegraphics[height=\baselineskip]{example-image-a}~#2},%
    title after break={\centering\footnotesize\itshape\strut Matlab Code~\thematlab~--~continued},%
     listing only,listing options={xleftmargin=-1mm,#1,style=Matlab-editor},
     after upper={\centering\strut {\bfseries Matlab Code~\thematlab:}~#2},
     frame hidden,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,boxrule=0pt,
     %
     listing file={#3},#1}

\usepackage[numbered,framed]{matlab-prettifier}

\begin{filecontents*}{sample.m}
% create a file for output
!touch testFile.txt
fid = fopen('testFile.text', 'w')
for i=1:10
  fprintf(fid,'%6.2f \n', i);
end
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\begin{codeblock}{Les bases de GDScript}
var nombreDeGardes = 4 #déclaration d'une variable
nombreDeGardes = plusDeux(nombreDeGardes) #appel d'une fonction avec la variable nombreDeGardes passée en paramètre

func maFonction(): #cette ligne déclare une nouvelle fonction nommée maFonction
    var variable1 = 7 #nouvelle variable dont la valeur est 7
    variable2 = ['un', 'deux', 'trois'] #variable assignée à un tableau contenant trois chaines de caractères

func plusDeux(argument1):
    return argument1 + 2
\end{codeblock}

\inputmatlab{Expansion Algorithm}{sample.m}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many options to vertically center an image, you may use a `parbox`, a `tabular`, the `valign=m` from adjustbox package, or simply the `\vcenter` macro in math-mode as follows.

```
\newcommand{\codeimg}{$\vcenter{\hbox{\includegraphics[height=\baselineskip]{example-image-a}}}$}
```

This is the only command you need to insert in the lists below.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt, oneside, fleqn, openright]{report}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{french}
\setotherlanguages{english}

\newcommand{\codeimg}{$\vcenter{\hbox{\includegraphics[height=\baselineskip]{example-image-a}}}$}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pdfpages,graphicx}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.92}

\definecolor{mainColor}{RGB}{211, 47, 47} % some dark red

\renewcommand\lstlistingname{Code}
\lstset{
    language=Python,
    numbers=left,
    numbersep= 7mm,
    numberstyle=\color{Black},
    stepnumber=1,
    tabsize=3,
    breakatwhitespace=false,
    breaklines=true,
    captionpos=b,
    basicstyle=\color{Black}\ttfamily,
    commentstyle=\color{LimeGreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{BurntOrange}\bfseries,
    stringstyle=\color{WildStrawberry},
    keywords={var, func, extends},
    frame=leftline,
    framesep=0mm,
    xleftmargin=3mm,% marge ajouté à gauche du tableau (à configurer en dernier pour l'alignement global du tableau)
    framesep=2mm, %distance texte bord du cadre (limite de la background color)
    framerule=0mm,
    abovecaptionskip=5mm,
    aboveskip=\baselineskip,
    belowskip=\baselineskip
}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\newcounter{data}
\newcounter{result}
\newcounter{pythoncode}
\newcounter{matlab}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable,listings}
\newtcblisting[use counter=lstlisting]{codeblock}[2][]{%
        enhanced,noparskip,breakable,colback=light-gray,colframe=DarkSlateGray,opacitybacktitle=.8,%
        fonttitle=\bfseries,before upper={\hspace*{-1em}\codeimg~#2},%
        title after break={\centering\footnotesize\itshape\strut\lstlistingname~\thelstlisting~--~continued},%
        listing only,listing options={xleftmargin=-1mm},
        after upper={\centering\strut\lstlistingname~\thelstlisting:~#2},
        frame hidden,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,boxrule=0pt,frame code={\draw[gray,line width=2mm] ([xshift=-0.5pt]frame.north west) -- ([xshift=-0.5pt]frame.south west);},#1}

\newtcbinputlisting[use counter=matlab,list inside=matlab,number within=chapter]{\inputmatlab}[3][]{listing options={style=Matlab-editor},%
        enhanced,noparskip,breakable,colback=light-gray,colframe=DarkSlateGray,opacitybacktitle=.8,%
        fonttitle=\bfseries,before upper={\hspace*{-1em}\codeimg~#2},%
    title after break={\centering\footnotesize\itshape\strut Matlab Code~\thematlab~--~continued},%
     listing only,listing options={xleftmargin=-1mm,#1,style=Matlab-editor},
     after upper={\centering\strut {\bfseries Matlab Code~\thematlab:}~#2},
     frame hidden,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,boxrule=0pt,
     %
     listing file={#3},#1}

\usepackage[numbered,framed]{matlab-prettifier}

\begin{filecontents*}{sample.m}
% create a file for output
!touch testFile.txt
fid = fopen('testFile.text', 'w')
for i=1:10
  fprintf(fid,'%6.2f \n', i);
end
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\begin{codeblock}{Les bases de GDScript}
var nombreDeGardes = 4 #déclaration d'une variable
nombreDeGardes = plusDeux(nombreDeGardes) #appel d'une fonction avec la variable nombreDeGardes passée en paramètre

func maFonction(): #cette ligne déclare une nouvelle fonction nommée maFonction
    var variable1 = 7 #nouvelle variable dont la valeur est 7
    variable2 = ['un', 'deux', 'trois'] #variable assignée à un tableau contenant trois chaines de caractères

func plusDeux(argument1):
    return argument1 + 2
\end{codeblock}

\inputmatlab{Expansion Algorithm}{sample.m}

\end{document}
```

[image]