# New List of "Contents" not appearing as the List of Figures

Tags: table-of-contents, tcolorbox

Thanks to [Dr. Christian Hupfer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/31729/christian-hupfer), he was able to generate a [table of contents for my "Data" and "Results" code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/353692/show-different-newtcbinputlistings-in-table-of-contents).  I was attempting to further his solution to have the Lists toc show up like my current List of Figures:

[image]

Currently, the "List of Data" and "List of Results" show up like this:

[image]

(the font and spacing between chapter list is different as compared to the List of Figures).

I am using a [`\newtcbinputlisting` environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/353463/color-and-formatting-does-not-show-in-multiple-listings) that was originally developed by [gernot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/110998/gernot).

I am using `titletoc` and `titlesec`, but I am not getting the same effect of the Data and Results list as I get for my Figures list.

Can you direct me as to how I can get the newly defined lists appear like the List of Figures?  Thanks!

Here is the code thus far:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{book}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pdfpages,graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\definecolor{myblueiii}{RGB}{199,234,253}
\definecolor{mybluei}{RGB}{0,173,239}
\definecolor{myblueii}{RGB}{63,200,244}

%======================================================================================
%   CHAPTER HEADINGS
%======================================================================================
\newcommand{\listofdataname}{List of Data}
\newcommand{\listofresultname}{List of Results}

\usepackage{titletoc}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc,arrows,shapes,decorations.pathreplacing,pgfplots.groupplots, matrix}

\usepackage[explicit,calcwidth]{titlesec}
\usepackage{fourier}

% List of figures
\titlecontents{figure}[0em]
{\addvspace{2pt}\sffamily}
{\thecontentslabel\hspace*{1em}}
{}
{\ \titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage}
[]

% List of data
\titlecontents{data}[0em]
{\addvspace{2pt}\sffamily}
{\thecontentslabel\hspace*{1em}}
{}
{\ \titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage}
[]

% List of data
\titlecontents{result}[0em]
{\addvspace{2pt}\sffamily}
{\thecontentslabel\hspace*{1em}}
{}
{\ \titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage}
[]

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\newcounter{data}
\newcounter{result}
\newcounter{pythoncode}
\newcounter{matlab}

%======================================================================================
%   HYPERLINKS IN THE DOCUMENTS
%======================================================================================

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,
            linkcolor = myblueii,
            backref=true,
            %pagebackref=true,
            hyperindex=true,
            breaklinks=true,
            urlcolor=blue,
            citecolor = ocre,
            bookmarks=true,
            bookmarksopen=false,
            pdftitle={Title},
            pdfauthor={Author}}

\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable,listings}
\newtcbinputlisting[use counter=data,list inside=data,number within=chapter]{\inputdata}[3][]{%
  title={Data~\thedata~ #2},
  title after break={\centering\footnotesize\itshape\strut Data~\thedata~--~continued},%
  listing only,listing options={xleftmargin=-1mm,#1,style=weka},after upper={\centering\strut Data~\thedata:~#2},%
  listing file={#3},#1}
\newtcbinputlisting[use counter=result,list inside=result,number within=chapter]{\inputresult}[3][]{%
  title={#2},
  enhanced,noparskip,breakable,colback=myblueiii,opacitybacktitle=.8,%
  title after break={\centering\footnotesize\itshape\strut Result~\theresult~--~continued},%
  listing only,listing options={xleftmargin=-1mm,#1,style=mystyleresults},after upper={\centering\strut Result~\theresult:~#2},%
  listing file={#3},#1}

\lstdefinestyle{mystyleresults}{
    commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{black},
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray},
    stringstyle=\color{black},
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize
}

\lstdefinestyle{weka}{
    numbers=none,
    numbersep=5pt,
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray},
    commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
}

\begin{filecontents}{result1.txt}
=== Run information ===

Correlation coefficient                  0.5941
Mean absolute error                      2.2173
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{result2.txt}

@attribute NUMUORS real   % Number of unique operators
@attribute NUMUANDS real  % Number of unique operands
@attribute TOTOTORS real  % Total number of operators

\end{filecontents}

\newcommand{\dataref}[1]{%
\hyperref[#1]{\textbf{\color{mybluei}Data \ref{#1}}}%
}

\newcommand{\resultref}[1]{%
\hyperref[#1]{\textbf{\color{mybluei}Result \ref{#1}}}%
}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures
\tcblistof[\chapter*]{data}{\listofdataname}
\tcblistof[\chapter*]{result}{\listofresultname}

\chapter{Data}
\section{Data1}
This is a reference for \dataref{data:D1} shown below.
\inputdata[label={data:D1}]{Code Snippet}{result2.txt}

\begin{figure}[!htbt]
\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{example-image-a}
\caption[Weka Preprocess Window for Fit.arff Data]{Weka Preprocess Window for Fit.arff Data.}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!htbt]
\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{example-image-b}
\caption[Weka Preprocess Window for Fit2.arff Data]{Weka Preprocess Window for Fit2.arff Data.}
\end{figure}

This is a reference for \dataref{data:D2} shown below.
\inputresult[label={data:D2}]{Code Snippet}{result1.txt}

\chapter{Analysis}
\section{Data44}
This is a reference for \dataref{data:D44} shown below.
\inputdata[label=data:D44]{Code Snippet}{result2.txt}

\begin{figure}[!htbt]
\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{example-image-b}
\caption[Weka Preprocess Window for Test.arff Data]{Weka Preprocess Window for Test.arff Data.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The reason is that `\chapter` does not add empty vertical space to the `.data` file etc. like it does for `.lot` or `.lot`. Don't use `titlesec` etc. for this!

Comment: Does any of your chapters have at least one result and data box?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The vertical spacing between figures from different chapters is introduced by the `\chapter` command and has nothing to do with `titletoc` etc. or `\tcblistof` settings.

The `\chapter` command is not aware of the fact that it should add this space for the `.data` and `.result` lists.

This can be cured, however, with the same statements as is done for `.lot` and `.lof` and prepending it to the `\chapter` command, for example.

```
\usepackage{xpatch}

\xpretocmd{\chapter}{%
  \addtocontents{data}{\protect\addvspace{10pt}}
  \addtocontents{result}{\protect\addvspace{10pt}}
}{}{}
```

Of course, the value of `10pt` can be changed at will...

However, this will add such spaces also to the relevant lists even if there's no data or result box. A better approach could be achieved with the `xcntperchap` package to trace the number of data or result boxes per chapter etc -- this will yield the means to control whether there should be an entry at all.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{book}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pdfpages,graphicx}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\definecolor{myblueiii}{RGB}{199,234,253}
\definecolor{mybluei}{RGB}{0,173,239}
\definecolor{myblueii}{RGB}{63,200,244}

%======================================================================================
%   CHAPTER HEADINGS
%======================================================================================
\newcommand{\listofdataname}{List of Data}
\newcommand{\listofresultname}{List of Results}

\usepackage{titletoc}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc,arrows,shapes,decorations.pathreplacing,pgfplots.groupplots, matrix}

\usepackage[explicit,calcwidth]{titlesec}
\usepackage{fourier}

% List of figures
\titlecontents{figure}[0em]
{\addvspace{2pt}\sffamily}
{\thecontentslabel\hspace*{1em}}
{}
{\ \titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage}
[]

% List of data
\titlecontents{data}[0em]
{\addvspace{2pt}\sffamily}
{\thecontentslabel\hspace*{1em}}
{}
{\ \titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage}
[]

% List of data
\titlecontents{result}[0em]
{\addvspace{2pt}\sffamily}
{\thecontentslabel\hspace*{1em}}
{}
{\ \titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage}
[]


\usepackage[skins,breakable,listings]{tcolorbox}
\newcounter{data}
\newcounter{result}
\newcounter{pythoncode}
\newcounter{matlab}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\xpretocmd{\chapter}{%
  \addtocontents{data}{\protect\addvspace{10pt}}
  \addtocontents{result}{\protect\addvspace{10pt}}
}{}{}


%======================================================================================
%   HYPERLINKS IN THE DOCUMENTS
%======================================================================================

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,
            linkcolor = myblueii,
            backref=true,
            %pagebackref=true,
            hyperindex=true,
            breaklinks=true,
            urlcolor=blue,
            citecolor = ocre,
            bookmarks=true,
            bookmarksopen=false,
            pdftitle={Title},
            pdfauthor={Author}}

\newtcbinputlisting[use counter=data,list inside=data,number within=chapter]{\inputdata}[3][]{%
  title={Data~\thedata~ #2},
  title after break={\centering\footnotesize\itshape\strut Data~\thedata~--~continued},%
  listing only,listing options={xleftmargin=-1mm,#1,style=weka},after upper={\centering\strut Data~\thedata:~#2},%
  listing file={#3},#1}
\newtcbinputlisting[use counter=result,list inside=result,number within=chapter]{\inputresult}[3][]{%
  title={#2},
  enhanced,noparskip,breakable,colback=myblueiii,opacitybacktitle=.8,%
  title after break={\centering\footnotesize\itshape\strut Result~\theresult~--~continued},%
  listing only,listing options={xleftmargin=-1mm,#1,style=mystyleresults},after upper={\centering\strut Result~\theresult:~#2},%
  listing file={#3},#1}

\lstdefinestyle{mystyleresults}{
    commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{black},
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray},
    stringstyle=\color{black},
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize
}

\lstdefinestyle{weka}{
    numbers=none,
    numbersep=5pt,
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray},
    commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
}

\begin{filecontents}{result1.txt}
=== Run information ===

Correlation coefficient                  0.5941
Mean absolute error                      2.2173
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{result2.txt}

@attribute NUMUORS real   % Number of unique operators
@attribute NUMUANDS real  % Number of unique operands
@attribute TOTOTORS real  % Total number of operators

\end{filecontents}

\newcommand{\dataref}[1]{%
\hyperref[#1]{\textbf{\color{mybluei}Data \ref{#1}}}%
}

\newcommand{\resultref}[1]{%
\hyperref[#1]{\textbf{\color{mybluei}Result \ref{#1}}}%
}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures
\tcblistof[\chapter*]{data}{\listofdataname}
\tcblistof[\chapter*]{result}{\listofresultname}

\chapter{Data}
\section{Data1}
This is a reference for \dataref{data:D1} shown below.
\inputdata[label={data:D1}]{Code Snippet}{result2.txt}

\begin{figure}[!htbt]
\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{example-image-a}
\caption[Weka Preprocess Window for Fit.arff Data]{Weka Preprocess Window for Fit.arff Data.}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!htbt]
\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{example-image-b}
\caption[Weka Preprocess Window for Fit2.arff Data]{Weka Preprocess Window for Fit2.arff Data.}
\end{figure}

This is a reference for \dataref{data:D2} shown below.
\inputresult[label={data:D2}]{Code Snippet}{result1.txt}

\chapter{Analysis}
\section{Data44}
This is a reference for \dataref{data:D44} shown below.
\inputdata[label=data:D44]{Code Snippet}{result2.txt}

\begin{figure}[!htbt]
\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{example-image-b}
\caption[Weka Preprocess Window for Test.arff Data]{Weka Preprocess Window for Test.arff Data.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your solution!  Just a little tweak...the list numbers should be not be hyperlinked and appear black like the List of Figures...is this an easy fix?

Comment: @Joe: No, no easy fix for the links. The colour is some `titletoc` issue, I won't attack that. In fact, you're construction a fragile building, actually, by adding one feature after another one -- this isn't good.

Comment: The xpatch works a bit like a document hook, doesnt it?

Comment: @MaestroGlanz: Well, like a macro hook rather.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, thanks again!  In order for this to work correctly, is it true that we have activate the `title` in the `newtcbinputlisting`?  Thanks!

Comment: @Joe: Either 'title=' or 'list='..., to format the title you have to use the regular facilities of `tcolorbox`.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, thanks again!  I was attempting to remove the `title` from the `newtcbinputlisting`, as I did not want the title to show up (like in the original question as I just have the title showing up at the bottom of the code).  When I removed the `title`, the name "tcolorbox" shows up for all the listings in the TOC.  I tried using the "listing name" but I could not it to work correctly.  Can the TOC show the name of the listing, without having the title appear in the `listbox`?  Thanks!

Comment: @Joe: What is the name of the listing? Please read the `tcolorbox` manual, p. 110 of current version (3.96), on `Lists of tcolorboxes`. If you want to achieve a completely different view of the toc entries, you have to change the `\l@data` etc. definitions. I won't do this, however.