# Change \tcolorbox tcblistof font formatting to match document's other lists

Tags: table-of-contents, tcblisting

This code is building from the solution [posted here by Dr. Hupfer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/353729/new-list-of-contents-not-appearing-as-the-list-of-figures).

I was attempting to get the font and other formatting of the `tcblistof` to match with the other lists in the document (like the list of Figures - see image below).

`tcblistof` appearance:

[image]

I would like this List of Data to look like the List of Figures:

[image]

Here is the code that was devised thus far:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pdfpages,graphicx}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[explicit,calcwidth]{titlesec}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[skins,breakable,listings]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\definecolor{myblueiii}{RGB}{199,234,253}
\definecolor{mybluei}{RGB}{0,173,239}
\definecolor{myblueii}{RGB}{63,200,244}

\newcommand{\listofdataname}{List of Data}
\newcommand{\listofresultname}{List of Results}

\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc,arrows,shapes,decorations.pathreplacing,pgfplots.groupplots, matrix}

% List of figures
\titlecontents{figure}[0em]
{\addvspace{2pt}\sffamily}
{\thecontentslabel\hspace*{1em}}
{}
{\ \titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage}
[]

% List of data
\titlecontents{data}[0em]
{\addvspace{2pt}\sffamily}
{\thecontentslabel\hspace*{1em}}
{}
{\ \titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage}
[]

% List of results
\titlecontents{result}[0em]
{\addvspace{2pt}\sffamily}
{\thecontentslabel\hspace*{1em}}
{}
{\ \titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage}
[]

\newcounter{data}
\newcounter{result}
\newcounter{pythoncode}
\newcounter{matlab}

\xpretocmd{\chapter}{%
  \addtocontents{data}{\protect\addvspace{10pt}}
  \addtocontents{result}{\protect\addvspace{10pt}}
}{}{}

%======================================================================================
%   HYPERLINKS IN THE DOCUMENTS
%======================================================================================

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,
            linkcolor = myblueii,
            backref=true,
            %pagebackref=true,
            hyperindex=true,
            breaklinks=true,
            urlcolor=blue,
            citecolor = ocre,
            bookmarks=true,
            bookmarksopen=false,
            pdftitle={Title},
            pdfauthor={Author}}

\newtcbinputlisting[use counter=data,list inside=data,number within=chapter]{\inputdata}[3][]{%
  list text = {#2},
  title after break={\centering\footnotesize\itshape\strut Data~\thedata~--~continued},%
  listing only,listing options={xleftmargin=-1mm,#1,style=weka},after upper={\centering\strut Data~\thedata:~#2},%
  listing file={#3},#1}
\newtcbinputlisting[use counter=result,list inside=result,number within=chapter]{\inputresult}[3][]{%
  list text = {#2},
  enhanced,noparskip,breakable,colback=myblueiii,opacitybacktitle=.8,%
  title after break={\centering\footnotesize\itshape\strut Result~\theresult~--~continued},%
  listing only,listing options={xleftmargin=-1mm,#1,style=mystyleresults},after upper={\centering\strut Result~\theresult:~#2},%
  listing file={#3},#1}

\lstdefinestyle{mystyleresults}{
    commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{black},
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray},
    stringstyle=\color{black},
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize
}

\lstdefinestyle{weka}{
    numbers=none,
    numbersep=5pt,
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray},
    commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
}

\begin{filecontents}{result1.txt}
=== Run information ===

Correlation coefficient                  0.5941
Mean absolute error                      2.2173
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{result2.txt}

@attribute NUMUORS real   % Number of unique operators
@attribute NUMUANDS real  % Number of unique operands
@attribute TOTOTORS real  % Total number of operators

\end{filecontents}

\newcommand{\dataref}[1]{%
\hyperref[#1]{\textbf{\color{mybluei}Data \ref{#1}}}%
}

\newcommand{\resultref}[1]{%
\hyperref[#1]{\textbf{\color{mybluei}Result \ref{#1}}}%
}

\makeatletter
\def\tcb@addcontentsline#1#2{%
  \ifx\kvtcb@listentry\@empty%
    \ifx\kvtcb@title\@empty%
      \ifx\tcbtitletext\@empty%
        \addcontentsline{#1}{#2}{{\ignorespaces\kvtcb@savedelimiter}}%
      \else%
        \addcontentsline{#1}{#2}{{\ignorespaces\tcbtitletext}}%
      \fi%
    \else%
      \addcontentsline{#1}{#2}{{\ignorespaces\kvtcb@title}}%
    \fi%
  \else%
    \addcontentsline{#1}{#2}{\kvtcb@listentry}%
  \fi%
}
\renewcommand{\l@tcolorbox}{\@dottedtocline{1}{0em}{2.3em}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\listoffigures
\tcblistof[\chapter*]{data}{\listofdataname}
\tcblistof[\chapter*]{result}{\listofresultname}

\chapter{Data}
\section{Data1}
This is a reference for \dataref{data:D1} shown below.
\inputdata[label={data:D1}]{CodeAA Snippet for data AA}{result2.txt}

This is a reference for \dataref{data:D1} shown below.
\inputdata[label={data:D1}]{CodeBB Snippet for data BB}{result2.txt}

\begin{figure}[!htbt]
\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{example-image-b}
\caption[Weka Preprocess Window for Fit.arff Data]{Weka Preprocess Window for Test.arff Data.}
\end{figure}

This is a reference for \dataref{data:D2} shown below.
\inputresult[label={data:D2}]{Data A Result Snippet}{result1.txt}

\begin{figure}[!htbt]
\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{example-image-b}
\caption[Weka Preprocess Window for Fit22.arff Data]{Weka Preprocess Window for Test.arff Data.}
\end{figure}

\chapter{Analysis}
\section{Data44}
This is a reference for \dataref{data:D44} shown below.
\inputdata[label=data:D44]{CodeBB Snippet}{result2.txt}

\begin{figure}[!htbt]
\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{example-image-b}
\caption[Weka Preprocess Window for Test.arff Data]{Weka Preprocess Window for Test.arff Data.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `list type=data` etc. settings must be used, however, this is not enough.

For some reason, `titletoc` does not define `\ttll@data` etc, so this has be done manually, i.e. `\renewcommand{\ttll@data}{-1000}` (to have the same effect like `\ttll@figure`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pdfpages,graphicx}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[skins,breakable,listings]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage[explicit,calcwidth]{titlesec}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\definecolor{myblueiii}{RGB}{199,234,253}
\definecolor{mybluei}{RGB}{0,173,239}
\definecolor{myblueii}{RGB}{63,200,244}

\newcommand{\listofdataname}{List of Data}
\newcommand{\listofresultname}{List of Results}

\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc,arrows,shapes,decorations.pathreplacing,pgfplots.groupplots, matrix}

% List of figures
\titlecontents{figure}[0em]
{\addvspace{2pt}\sffamily}
{\thecontentslabel\hspace*{1em}}
{}
{\ \titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage}
[]

% List of data
\titlecontents{data}[0em]
{\addvspace{2pt}\sffamily}
{\thecontentslabel\hspace*{1em}}
{}
{\ \titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage}%
[]

% List of results
\titlecontents{result}[0em]
{\addvspace{2pt}\sffamily}
{\thecontentslabel\hspace*{1em}}
{}
{\ \titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage}
[]

\newcounter{data}
\newcounter{result}
\newcounter{pythoncode}
\newcounter{matlab}

\xpretocmd{\chapter}{%
  \addtocontents{data}{\protect\addvspace{10pt}}
  \addtocontents{result}{\protect\addvspace{10pt}}
}{}{}

%======================================================================================
%   HYPERLINKS IN THE DOCUMENTS
%======================================================================================

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,
            linkcolor = myblueii,
            backref=true,
            %pagebackref=true,
            hyperindex=true,
            breaklinks=true,
            urlcolor=blue,
            citecolor = ocre,
            bookmarks=true,
            bookmarksopen=false,
            pdftitle={Title},
            pdfauthor={Author}}

\newtcbinputlisting[use counter=data,list inside=data,number within=chapter,list type=data]{\inputdata}[3][]{%
  list text = {#2},
  title after break={\centering\footnotesize\itshape\strut Data~\thedata~--~continued},%
  listing only,listing options={xleftmargin=-1mm,#1,style=weka},after upper={\centering\strut Data~\thedata:~#2},%
  listing file={#3},#1}
\newtcbinputlisting[use counter=result,list inside=result,number within=chapter,list type=result]{\inputresult}[3][]{%
  list text = {#2},
  enhanced,noparskip,breakable,colback=myblueiii,%opacitybacktitle=.8,%
  title after break={\centering\footnotesize\itshape\strut Result~\theresult~--~continued},%
  listing only,listing options={xleftmargin=-1mm,#1,style=mystyleresults},after upper={\centering\strut Result~\theresult:~#2},%
  listing file={#3},#1}

\lstdefinestyle{mystyleresults}{
    commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{black},
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray},
    stringstyle=\color{black},
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize
}

\lstdefinestyle{weka}{
    numbers=none,
    numbersep=5pt,
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray},
    commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
}

\begin{filecontents}{result1.txt}
=== Run information ===

Correlation coefficient                  0.5941
Mean absolute error                      2.2173
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{result2.txt}

@attribute NUMUORS real   % Number of unique operators
@attribute NUMUANDS real  % Number of unique operands
@attribute TOTOTORS real  % Total number of operators

\end{filecontents}

\newcommand{\dataref}[1]{%
  \hyperref[#1]{\textbf{\color{mybluei}Data \ref*{#1}}}%
}

\newcommand{\resultref}[1]{%
  \hyperref[#1]{\textbf{\color{mybluei}Result \ref*{#1}}}%
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\ttll@data}{-1000}
\newcommand{\ttll@result}{-1000}

\makeatother





\begin{document}


\listoffigures
\tcblistof[\chapter*]{data}{\listofdataname}
\tcblistof[\chapter*]{result}{\listofresultname}

\chapter{Data}
\section{Data1}
This is a reference for \dataref{data:D1} shown below.
\inputdata[label={data:D1}]{CodeAA Snippet for data AA}{result2.txt}

This is a reference for \dataref{data:D1} shown below.
\inputdata[label={data:D11}]{CodeBB Snippet for data BB}{result2.txt}

\begin{figure}[!htbt]
\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{example-image-b}
\caption[Weka Preprocess Window for Fit.arff Data]{Weka Preprocess Window for Test.arff Data.}
\end{figure}

This is a reference for \dataref{data:D2} shown below.
\inputresult[label={data:D2}]{Data A Result Snippet}{result1.txt}

\begin{figure}[!htbt]
\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{example-image-b}
\caption[Weka Preprocess Window for Fit22.arff Data]{Weka Preprocess Window for Test.arff Data.}
\end{figure}

\chapter{Analysis}
\section{Data44}
This is a reference for \dataref{data:D44} shown below.
\inputdata[label=data:D44]{CodeBB Snippet}{result2.txt}

\begin{figure}[!htbt]
\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{example-image-b}
\caption[Weka Preprocess Window for Test.arff Data]{Weka Preprocess Window for Test.arff Data.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]